# Django - Retrieve url origin from view - multiple urls to 1 view

Tags: django, django-views

I have several urls mapping to one view. Inside the url, I would like to know the url origin? It is to avoid writing multiple views (DRY).

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('path1/', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
  path('path2/', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
   url_origin = ... #would like path1 or path2
```

I looked for 'reverse' but it does not seem to be a solution to my problem. It returns an error.

```
reverse('index')
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the original path with [**`request.path`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path) (so in a view function for a class-based view, you can access this with `self.request.path`.

You can however fix this, for example by providing an extra parameter, like:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('path1/', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index1', kwargs={'through': 'path1'}),
  path('path2/', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index2', kwargs={'through': 'path2'})
]
```

Then you can inspect the `self.kwargs['through']` parameter in your class-based view.

Note that you better give the different paths a *different* name, since otherwise, it will indeed raise an error. By giving these as name `'index1'` and `'index2'`, you can simply use `reverse('index1')`, and it is not ambiguous to what URL it should redirect.